# Netbeans GUI builder and Jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am having some difficulty with getting a JTable to appear within a JPanel. I have built the UI using the Netbeans GUI builder and then created the jtable from code and attempted to add to an existing GUI built jpanel. I can't work out what the problem is.  Code for the jtable part of the code is shown below  (data is made up). I suspect I am missing some step which is needed when using the GUI builder as I can get a jtable to work if I do not use the GUI builder

```
   private void fillOrderDetailsJtable (){

        String[] columnNames = {"Order Line No", "Product", "Quantity" };

        Object[][] data = {
           {"César Cielo", "Filho", "Brazil", "50m freestyle" },
           {"Amaury", "Leveaux", "France", "50m freestyle"},
           {"Eamon", "Sullivan", "Australia", "100m freestyle"},

        }; 
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        tableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

        pnOrderLines.add(tableScrollPane);

        Order_OrderLine.this.add(pnOrderLines); 
         // table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        tableScrollPane.setVisible(true);
        pnOrderLines.setVisible(true);
        table.setVisible(true);          
   }
```

Comment: `I can get a jtable to work if I do not use the GUI builder` - which is what you should be doing. Don't use an IDE to generate a form for you. If you ever switch IDE's the code will not be maintainable in the other IDE. By coding the form yourself you spend time learning Swing and not the IDE. Use the IDE only to help compile and debug the code you write. ` Code for the jtable part of the code is shown below` - which doesn't help because we don't know the context of how that code is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did you place the JTable to the Form and check the code Netbeans generates before trying it from the scratch?

This is IMHO the easiest way to get a clue of constructing forms.

I would suppose that you do this and compare the generated code to your own.

There is some sample code:

```
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
      new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
      },
      new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
      }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(158, 100, 292, 246);

    pack();
```

Comment: Thanks Maia  using your answer I managed to work out the problem.

Comment: @RichardFaint good to hear that it worked for you. What was the missing Thing? SetBounds()?

Comment: Hi Maia, yes it was the set bounds bit that was missing